# How do I call a DOM's method from PHP?

Tags: php, dom

```
  <?php
     session_start();

      echo "<script language='javascript'>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
          function(){
                    console.log('11');
                    console.log(document.getElementById('#login_links_login'));
                          })
    </script>";
 ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <body>
         <!-- form goes here -->
     </body>
  </html>
```

This is my PHP code. It is at the top of my page. After this I have HTML form.

I want to open my HTML form from php. I know that I can do it from jQuery/JavaScript or keep it open. I want it from PHP for my another purpose.

But console returns

```
 11
 null
```

But I included those two lines inside `DomContentLoaded` method of JavaScript. But it doesn't work.

My browsers are Mozilla, WebKit.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure #login_links_login is in the DOM at the time DOMContentLoaded is fired?

Comment: Please show the relevant portion of the HTML including #login_links_login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an element with the HTML attribute `id="login_links_login"`, you need to remove the `#` from your string to `document.getElementById`.

The `#<id>` syntax is the CSS-selector style, which is supported by jQuery, some others and is probably going to be standardised by W3, but is not (yet) part of normal JavaScript or the ECMAScript standard.

*Edit:*
And you should really **not** output **anything** before `<html>` or after `</html>` (although it will still work with most browsers).

Comment: Thanks. I am redirecting to this page from my registration validation php page. So i need to open login window if any errors are there. So i must have this outside html. isn't?

Comment: If you do that in JS, no. JS runs in the browser, it *is part* of the HTML page, therefore it should be somewhere between `<html>` and `</html>`. PHP, on the other hand, **prints** that whole HTML page and therefore **cannot** be a part of it. But in PHP you can't open a window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<?php
 session_start();
 //MAKE THE CODE CLEAR
?>

  <script language='javascript'>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      console.log('11');
      console.log(document.getElementById('login_links_login'));//REMOVE THE #
  });
</script>
<?php

?>
```

Comment: I just added there that i want to do it from php for other purpose

Comment: @GopsAB OK, so why the downvote? That does'nt mean that you should downvote this answer. Because the `#` removal thing may solve your problem -_-